# Simulation of a process consist of Brownian motion and Poisson process

Tags: stochastic-processes, point-process

I am trying to simulate the following process:

```
h(t)=B(t)+e[P1(t)-P2(t)]
```

in which B(t) is a Brownian motion and P1, P2 are Poisson process with    `lambda=5000` and `t<-1:10000` and I choose `e=0.5`. I am able to simulate `B(t)` wiht the following code:

```
x <- rnorm(n = length(t) - 1, sd = sqrt(0.01)) 
B <- c(0, cumsum(x))
```

and one Poisson process

```
P1<-cumsum(rpois(10000,5000/10000))
```

P2 is also poisson process with the same rate so that the difference between `P1` and `P2` will be a process that jumps around `0` as follow:
`...0,lambda,-2*lambda,lambda,0...`. I created `P2` the same way I did for `P1` and plot the difference `P1-P2` but the result is not as I expected

I wonder if my algorithm to create `P1` and `P2` is correct? Can someone please tell me the step that I went wrong?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think `P1 - P2` will behave like that? Your sample looks deterministic, but `P1 - P2` will be random.

Comment: sorry, this is my clarification for how I expected the difference `P1-P2` behave: since the jump of Poisson process is 1, the difference of 2 Poisson processes should evolve around 0 with the jump of either 1 or -1. Therefore, `h(t)` will have the jump of 0.5 or -0.5 when the difference is not 0